# Exchange Mailbox Users to PowerBi

Tags: powershell, azure-active-directory, powerbi

Is it possible to connect mailbox users and group list from exchange/azure AD to have a whole list in PowerBI?

So far I have export the list by PowerShell but I need to have this somehow automated.

Comment: Have you looked into the azure runbook(PowerShell type) to do that automatically? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/automation-first-runbook-textual-powershell

Comment: It should be possible using Microsoft Graph API. Check [Connect to the Microsoft Graph Security API in Power BI Desktop](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/desktop-connect-graph-security)

Comment: I will check both suggestions, many thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use Microsoft Graph Security (Beta) which is available for PowerBI Desktop application.

To use the Microsoft Graph Security connector, you must explicitly get consent by the Azure Active Directory (Azure AD) tenant administrator. See [Microsoft Graph Security authentication requirements](https://aka.ms/graphsecurityauth). Consent requires the connector's application ID and name, which is cited here and is available in the Azure portal:

To grant consent for the connector, your Azure AD tenant administrator can use either of these methods:

1. Grant consent for Azure AD applications
2. Respond to a request that your logic app submits during its first
   run through the application-consent experience
3. The user account that signs in to the Microsoft Graph Security
   connector must be a member of the Security Reader Limited Admin role
   in Azure AD, either as Security Reader or Security Administrator.
   See Assign Azure AD roles to users.

and then Follow these steps to use the connector:

1. Select Get Data > More from the Home ribbon in Power BI Desktop.
2. Select Online Services from the categories list on the left side of
   the window.
3. Select Microsoft Graph Security (Beta).

[image]
 4. In the Microsoft Graph Security window, select the Microsoft Graph
    API version to query: v1.0 or beta.
[image]
 5. Sign in to your Azure Active Directory account when you're prompted.
    This account needs to have the Security Reader or Security
    Administrator role, as mentioned in the previous section.
[image]
 6. If you're the tenant admin and you don't yet have consent to the
    Microsoft Graph Security Power BI connector (application), you'll
    see the following dialog box. Select Consent on behalf of your
    organization.
 7. When you're signed in, you'll see the following dialog box that indicates that you've been authenticated. Select Connect.
[image]

After you connect, the Navigator window displays the alerts, secure scores, and other entities that are available in the Microsoft Graph Security API for the version that you selected in step 4. Select one or more entities to import and use in Power BI Desktop. Then, select Load to get the result view that's shown after step 9.

[image]

If you want to use an advanced query with the Microsoft Graph Security API, select Specify custom Microsoft Graph Security URL to filter results.

Hope it helps.